# Show Loading Dialog When Making A HTTP Request in Android

Tags: android

In an effort to learn Android I am writing a small app. The first thing I am trying to do is login via a remote API.

I would like to show a "loading" dialog when the call is being made (in case he user in using mobile internet). Researching this has shown two possible methods.

One is to use a **ProgressDialog** and a private class that extends **Thread**, the other is using a private class that extends **AsyncTask**.

Which is best/more appropriate for this task?

I have tried using the ProgressDialog version but am struggling. I have put the function making the http request in the extended Thread run() method, but am unsure on how to pass the response data (JSON) back into my activity.

Any and all help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way possible is to use an `AsyncTask` with a `ProgressDialog`. You should extend `AsyncTask` and implement all the methods you need:

- `onPreExecute()` - here you initialize your `ProgressDialog` and `show()` it
- `doInBackground()` - here you do your work
- `onPostExecute()` - here you call `dismiss()` on `ProgressDialog` to hide it
- (optional) `onProgressUpdate()` - here you can change the progress of your `ProgressDialog` if it's determinate

There is a `get()` method in `AsyncTask` class that lets you retrieve the result of the work. Also you can implement an interface between the `AsyncTask` and calling `Activity` to return the result. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info (upvoted). How do I call the get() method as I have read that you are not allowed to call AsynTask methods directly?

Comment: the methods are called in order once you new YourAsyncTask().execute();

Comment: @Rooneyl, The methods I described in my answer are all protected, and get() is a public method, you can call it with no problems. Usually it looks like that: Object result = new Task().execute().get();

Answer (score 0):

Efforts come with rewards :) Egor is right, AsyncTask is the best way to do it. But
You have to know that Activity is working on the UI thread and threads not. So the only way to share things is via handler. Here an example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);       
    handler= new Handler();     
}

public void startProgress(View view) {
    // Do something long
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```